# Tableau grouping on a calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

[image: Example data set]

I wanted to get for how many MKT  6/5/.... is repeated.
i.e count of mkts group by CNTD(no.week sale) column .

is there any way to achieve this.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Create calculated field CF1 as

{FIXED [Prod], [MKT] : COUNTD([No.week sale])}

Then put  [Prod] and [CF1] on columns shelf, COUNTD([MKT]) on Label (Text) mark

Comment: Thanks! But this will not give me what I am looking for . I wanted the count of mkts group by no.week sale column

Comment: Do you want to exclude [Prod] from viz or to group by [No.week sale]), not COUNTD([No.week sale]) ?